Issues when installing Plone 6 CMS through Pipx Cookiecutter
I'm trying to install Plone following the suggested steps on their website. I've ensured that all dependencies are installed and working. I've also installed Pipx and Cookiecutter subsequently, and I can successfully clone project starters through it.
However, when I execute the pipx run cookiecutter gh:collective/cookiecutter-plone-starter command to start a Plone project, I encounter the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Path\To\Python\Python3\Lib\shutil.py", line 620, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Path\\To\\User\\Directory\\.cookiecutters\\cookiecutter-plone-starter\\{{ cookiecutter.project_slug }}\\backend\\src\\{{ cookiecutter.python_package_name }}\\src\\{{ cookiecutter.python_package_name }}\\locales\\{{ cookiecutter.__locales_language }}\\LC_MESSAGES\\{{ cookiecutter.python_package_name }}.po'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Scripts\cookiecutter.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\cli.py", line 203, in main
    cookiecutter(
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\main.py", line 80, in cookiecutter
    base_repo_dir, cleanup_base_repo_dir = determine_repo_dir(
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\repository.py", line 108, in determine_repo_dir
    cloned_repo = clone(
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\vcs.py", line 99, in clone
    clone = prompt_and_delete(repo_dir, no_input=no_input)
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\prompt.py", line 401, in prompt_and_delete
    rmtree(path)
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\utils.py", line 34, in rmtree
    shutil.rmtree(path, onerror=force_delete)
  File "C:\Path\To\Python\Python3\Lib\shutil.py", line 759, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Path\To\Python\Python3\Lib\shutil.py", line 617, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Path\To\Python\Python3\Lib\shutil.py", line 617, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Path\To\Python\Python3\Lib\shutil.py", line 617, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  [Previous line repeated 6 more times]
  File "C:\Path\To\Python\Python3\Lib\shutil.py", line 622, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Path\To\pipx\.cache\3f5e789ca8f97a2\Lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\utils.py", line 25, in force_delete
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Path\\To\\User\\Directory\\.cookiecutters\\cookiecutter-plone-starter\\{{ cookiecutter.project_slug }}\\backend\\src\\{{ cookiecutter.python_package_name }}\\src\\{{ cookiecutter.python_package_name }}\\locales\\{{ cookiecutter.__locales_language }}\\LC_MESSAGES\\{{ cookiecutter.python_package_name }}.po'

After prompting the Do you want to re-use the existing version? \[y/n\] (y): question, it seems to not be able to delete the old file to create a new one.
Additionally, when I try to use the existing project, I receive the following message:
A valid repository for "https://github.com/collective/cookiecutter-plone-starter.git" could not be found in the following locations:
C:\Users\.cookiecutters\cookiecutter-plone-starter

Even though this is a valid path.
How can I create a project normally without encountering these errors?

Maybe as in https://community.plone.org/
